# Nested for-loop iteration stops

Tags: python, for-loop, iteration, lxml

I have two input files: an html one, and a css for it. I want to produce some operation on the html file based on the contents of the css file.

my html is like this:

```
<html>
 <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p class = "cl1" id = "id1"> <span id = "span1"> blabla</span> </p>
    <p class = "cl2" id = "id2"> <span id = "span2"> blablabla</span> <span id = "span3"> qwqwqw </span> </p>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Styles for span ids are defined in the css file (individually for each span id!)

Before doing real stuff (deletion of spans based on their style) I was trying just to print out ids from the html and the style descritption from the css corresponding to each id.

Code:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.parse("file.html")

filein = "file.css"


def f1():

    with open(filein, 'rU') as f:   
        for span in tree.iterfind('//span'):   
            for line in f:
                if span and span.attrib.has_key('id'):
                    x = span.get('id')
                    if "af" not in x and x in line:
                            print x, line
def main():
     f1()
```

So, there are two for-loops, which iterate perfectly if separated, but when put together in this function the iteration stops after the first loop:

```
>> span1 span`#span1 { font-weight: bold; font-size: 11.0pt; font-style: normal; letter-spacing: 0em }
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If as I think, tree is completely loaded in memory, you could try to reverse the loops. That way, you only browse the file `filein` once :

```
def f1():

    with open(filein, 'rU') as f:   
        for line in f:
            for span in tree.iterfind('//span'):   
                if span and span.attrib.has_key('id'):
                    x = span.get('id')
                    if "af" not in x and x in line:
                            print x, line
```

Answer (score 1):

It happens because you have read all filein lines till second outer loop begin.
To make it work, you need add f.seek(0) before starting inner loop over filein:

```
with open(filein, 'rU') as f:   
    for span in tree.iterfind('//span'):
        f.seek(0)   
        for line in f:
            if span and span.attrib.has_key('id'):
                x = span.get('id')
                if "af" not in x and x in line:
                        print x, line
```

Comment: thank you for the hint! I didn't know about this seek function. спасибо))